# Unable to insert in a <tr> the content of an attribute from XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to do a simple XSL conversion from an XML file that I receive from a rest call using a script in VB wrote by myself. This is XML that I receive (after clean up):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <result xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.teradp.com/schemas/GN4/1/Results.xsd">
        <objsListResult>
            <obj id="4" descName="Administrator user" />
            <obj id="5" descName="Guest" />
            <obj id="1608" descName="MashupUser" />
            <obj id="1610" descName="ServiceUser" />
            <obj id="2209" descName="Brenda Perez Lastra" />
        </objsListResult>
    </result>
```

This is the simple XSL file that I wrote for it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>GN4 User Information</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Obj ID</th>
        <th>User Complete Name</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> <xsl:value-of select="obj/@id"/></td>
        <td> Some Text </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The HTML code that XSLT makes show the table and you can see the cell with "Some Text" written on it (as I specified in the XSL code) but when it comes to print the content of the "id" attribute I receive nothing. I played with the Xpath a little bit thinking that I did something wrong in the path but I always receive nothing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of problems:

1. You're not actually applying a template to the `obj` nodes that (I'm assuming) you want iterate over.
2. Your input document has a default namespace URI.  This is a very common issue when getting started with XSLT.

I've annotated the following transform to help clarify the changes from your original.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                            xmlns:gn="http://www.teradp.com/schemas/GN4/1/Results.xsd">

  <!-- Note that you need to match the namespace of the nodes in the input
         document.  This namespace is declared above, and needs to be used with
         each element in an XPath expression where you expect to match a node with
         that namespace URI. -->
  <xsl:template match="/gn:result">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>GN4 User Information</h2>
            <table border="1">
                <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                    <th>Obj ID</th>
                    <th>User Complete Name</th>
                </tr>

                <!-- Right now the context node is the root "gn:result" element
                         (because that's what this template matched).  From here, apply
                         the row template on the "gn:obj" elements.  Everything else in
                         this template is essentially static content. -->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="gn:objsListResult/gn:obj" />
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- When this template is called, it will be executed once for each gn:obj
         element that matches. -->
  <xsl:template match="gn:obj">
    <tr>
        <!-- Attributes don't need to be namespaced. -->
        <td> <xsl:value-of select="@id"/></td>
        <td> Some Text </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input, it produces the following output (indented for clarity):

```
<html xmlns:gn="http://www.teradp.com/schemas/GN4/1/Results.xsd">
    <body>
        <h2>GN4 User Information</h2>
        <table border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                <th>Obj ID</th>
                <th>User Complete Name</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td> Some Text </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td> Some Text </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1608</td>
                <td> Some Text </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1610</td>
                <td> Some Text </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2209</td>
                <td> Some Text </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I think this is what you're going for.